# What's the meaning of "Don't forget to add the script to the CMakeLists.txt install rule"

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am parctising this web page:

http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf2%20listener%20%28Python%29

There is one sentence:

Don't forget to add the script to the CMakeLists.txt install rule, reinvoke catkin_make_isolated and use your terminal with the devel_isolated/setup.bash sourced.

I don't understand the meaning of "Don't forget to add the script to the CMakeLists.txt install rule", what should be done according to it?

What scirpt? Where to add?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349625/what%27s-the--meaning-of-%22don%27t-forget-to-add-the-script-to-the-cmakelists.txt-install-rule%22/) by [Dean](https://answers.ros.org/users/53030/dean/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2020-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It means to use the install CMake command like: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/melodic-devel/map_server/CMakeLists.txt#L101.

This makes it available in your install space and not just your devel space for debug.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dean](https://answers.ros.org/users/53030/dean/) on 2020-04-28**:
Thank you very much.